# How to serialize the result from select_related query in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, serialization

i want to join two tables using django select_related. But how can i serialize those data from two tables to get serialized details including full image url from another table

My View.py

```
class getALlUserProfileDataAPIView(views.APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request):

        #usedraa = User.objects.filter(qs).select_related('userAddress').values('id','useraddress__country',  'useraddress__state',  'useraddress__city','email','username','first_name','last_name','password')

        usedraa = User.objects.filter().select_related('Profile').values('username','profile__image','first_name','last_name')
        #usedraa = User.objects.all().prefetch_related()
        userProfileSerializer0 = userProfileSerializer(usedraa, context={'request': request}, many=True)

        return Response(userProfileSerializer0.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Serailizer

```
ass userProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    prodata = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(read_only=True,  view_name = 'profile')
  #  prodata = ProfileSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)  # many=True is required
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("first_name","last_name","username","prodata")
```

Comment: Read [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships). It shows how to add a nested serialised for the related model. `select_related` has nothing to do with it, it's just convenient to avoid multiple database calls. Replace `Album` and `Track` with `User` and `Profile`.

Comment: But i don't want nested information i want it without nesting just like the response of select related

Comment: In that case, use a [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). Your method will have access to the `obj` as passed in by your QuerySet, so it will be the `values` dictionary.

Comment: @dirkgroten, are there any other ways to answer the OP without using the Django Rest Framework? (I see [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) is part of the DRF. I have the same question, and I've like to avoid using it, and I assume the OP would as well (seeing as they didn't mention the DRF). E.g. using [django.core.serializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/serialization/) which is built in.

Comment: The OP didn’t mention it explicitly but OP is using DRF: the `APIView` and  `ModelSerializer` classes come from DRF.